# Why on verify email address on smtp.gmail.com always response 250 ok for valid email address and invalid one?. do i try another way? miss something

Tags: email, verify

using Cygwin terminal, command openssl s_client -connect smtp -connect smtp.gmail.com:465  -crlf -ign_eof

auth plain encrypted username and password, succeed to send mail, but command rcpt to: always response 250 ok

Comment: What would you expect the response to be?  If you're authenticated and not using gmail as a relay, then it won't know that the sender is invalid until it tries to send the message...

Comment: rcpt to: what? a gmail address? Or another address on the open internet? As Martin says, it has no way to know about other organizations email addresses.

Comment: I guess you are right, in spite of many comments from other people that rcpt to: verify existence of email address on mail servers. – Hazem Mohamed just now